# how to read a Textbox?

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
TextBox[,] tb = new TextBox[x,y];
```

How do I read value from TextBox[0,0] for example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text.aspx) property. Same as for a single TextBox.

```
Console.WriteLine(tb[0,0].Text);
```

*Remember to access it with variable name `tb` as you have defined in your code. It may be better to name your TextBox array to something more understandable.*